# giving context to an asyncData returned object

Tags: nuxt.js

Here's what I need to achieve somehow:

```
  asyncData(ctx) {
    return {
      myclass: new ClassWithCtx(ctx.app)
    }
  },
```

Unfortunately, this returns `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

I understand why this happens: the server-side rendered content must be serialized to be sent back to the client, and as many modules into the context already holds this same context, the serialization ends up with an infinite loop.

I thought about setting the context from `mounted()` instead, but my components need this when server-side rendered, which makes it fail.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: what usecase are you trying here?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I never got the notification... Basically, asyncData retrieves data from an external API an provision a custom class which requires the context to access modules like axios or i18n.